# gerrit cherry pick link missing in gerrit web

Tags: git, gerrit

I installed gerrit version 2.11.3, in that i am not able to find cherry-pick link in gerrit change. Can be seen in [attached screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rstM.png).
How to enable the cherry-pick option in gerrit?

Comment: Do you mean you don't see the cherry-pick button? Or clicking the cherry-pick button don't display any link?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the '**download-commands**' plugin. You (or your sysadmin) can do that with the following command:

`$ java -jar gerrit.war init -d {gerrit-instance} --install-plugin=download-commands`